# Markers with different colors in Cluster. Open Layer 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

Good Morning:

I am using Open Layer 3 for show a map. I am adding markers by Cluster. The idea is join the markers according with the size. [image]

So. I am trying to add the markers with different colors.

In my features, when I print the markers, I can get the icons and they are differents. Let me show it.

var featured = feature.get('features');

var icon = featured[0]["R"]['icon'];

icon = "http://localhost:8000/img/icons/user_yellow.png"

But, the cluster, show me only "http://localhost:8000/img/icons/user_blue.png"

They are my functions:

```
 // this function computes a text style
    // based on the size of a cluster
    // the style is cached
    function getTextStyle(text) {
      var key = 'text' + text;

      if (!cache[key]) {
      if(text == 1){
        cache[key] = new ol.style.Style({
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '22px sans-serif',
            text: text,
            textBaseline: 'alphabetic',
            offsetY: 15,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'transparent'
            })
          })
        });
      }else{
         cache[key] = new ol.style.Style({
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '22px sans-serif',
            text: text,
            textBaseline: 'alphabetic',
            offsetY: 15,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'black'
            })
          })
        });     
      }
     }
      return cache[key];
    }



    // this function computes a circle style
    // based on the size of a cluster
    // the style is cached.
    function getCircleStyle(size,icon) {
      var key = 'circle' + size;     
      if (!cache[key]) {
        cache[key] = new ol.style.Style({
           image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            opacity: 1,
            src: icon,
           }))
        });
      }
      return cache[key];
    }


    // the style function for the cluster layer combines
// a circle and a text style based on the size of the cluster
function clusterStyle(feature, resolution) {

  var size = feature.get('features').length;
  var featured = feature.get('features'); 
  var icon = featured[0]["R"]['icon'];
  var pointStyle = getCircleStyle(size,icon);
  var textStyle = getTextStyle(size.toString());
  return [pointStyle, textStyle];
}
```

I don´t know why the function show me the icons with only one color.

It is my VectorLayer

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: clusterStyle
});

Comment: put a breakpoint or some console.log in there to see what  happens

Comment: When I add a console.log, en "icon" variable, it show me the color that I want. But the cluster don't show it. Only show blue color.

Comment: See: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html, use a color depending on something (size, coords, ...).

Comment: I used this example.  However, I only can see #3399CC color. It not change. Thanks.

Comment: I do not think the cluster algorithm was designed to have separate colors.

Comment: Mmm, I do not hope so. Anyway,  many thanks. I am going to try to get another code.